# iOS UITableViewCell accessory not showing correctly except Disclosure Indicator

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a project with a UITableViewController, and I configure the prototype cells like the image below:

[image]

I set the prototype cell from row 3~6 to "Disclosure Indicator", "Detail Disclosure", "Checkmark" and "Detail" respectively, but it seems that only the "Disclosure Indicator" works, the icons of "Checkmark" and "Detail" are missing, just some spaces.

First I thought it maybe a bug of the storyboard, but after I run the project on device, the problem remains the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that's because I set the `Global Tint` Color to `White`, and the table view cell's background color is also white.

The reason why only the "Disclosure Indicator" works is because only "Disclosure Indicator" is not affected by the Tint color.